# How to set output paths in powershell?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powershell, asp.net-web-api2

I have two questions

1st) I have multiple class libraries in my solution so how can I set output Path of some specific folder of any class library.

2nd) I know how to create new classes via scaffold command in Package Manager Console but what can I do if I have to update any existing class, say DBContext class where we have to add DBSet property of every new Model class?

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but how are these things relevant to each other? You don't need to learn PowerShell to use T4? `$outputPath`? Are you conflating msbuild with powershell?

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question. I need to learn these things in powershell.